# In OS X, how do you get the finder's path bar to show server name?

Tags: macos, path, finder

I usually have one or two hosts (also Macs) in my finder side bar "Shared" section and often want to navigate to a folder in one of those hosts.  I have the path bar on the bottom of the finder window turned on, but I can't tell from the path bar which host I'm looking at.  So if I go to (server1) MyUserHomeDirectory/Documents , the path bar shows MyUserHomeDirectory > Documents .  If I do the same but for server2, I'll see the exact same path in the path bar.  I can't tell which remote host's path the path bar is referring to.  Is there a way to have the path bar show the host?  Maybe get the hosts' shared name in the sidebar to light up or something?

Comment: it's not really an answer but maybe a possible workaround for you too - when i am working with network files (files on servers) i don't use Finder i use Transmit which enables me to have both Local an Remote Location open next to each other at the same time inside the same window. there i can clearly tell on which server i am